# Hold back mysql database queries

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I have got a mysql database and a cache (memcached) in front of it.

Basically I don't want to allow any request go to my database. Instead, all request should be answered by the cache.

However the cache is flushed every 10 minutes and then requests go to my database until the cache is updated with the recent data. But this can lead to traffic spikes for a few time!!

How can I hold back requests or let only one of them go through to my database until the cache is updated again?

```
$get_result = $memcache->get('key'); //retrieve memcached data if possible
if($get_result){
    // Show the memcached result
}else {
   // Make request to the database 
   ...
   // and re-set the cache
   $memcache->set('key', $get_result, false, 600); 
}
```

Comment: Seems like y ou are wanting to disable cache flushing but you dont seems to understand how a cahce works ... it has to be able to hit the database to refresh

Comment: Why are you flushing your entire cache at once? Why not give 10 min TTL on the items such that requests after the TTL hit the database to repopulate the cache on a per item basis, not for the entire cache at once?

Comment: Even on a per item basis, if the item gets flushed and then immediatelly requested by a few 100 of people they are all going to the DB right now

Answer (score 0):

The following is totally theoretical, since I don't know PHP. But it works using the C interface, so I suppose it should work in a web service as well.

There are two time constants, and you need to choose them carefully. One is the amount of time you're willing to wait for the cached to be filled. I'd suggest about half the amount of time you expect a refill to take, although it could be even less if refill time (database lookup) is high. Polling memcached doesn't cost that much, but you don't want to do it every three microseconds, I don't think. The other one is the expiry of the special token in the first line. I set it to 1 (one second) because that's the smallest possible value, but it shouldn't be less than the expected refill time. Of course, the expected refill time will normally be less than a second.

Note: I used the memcached interface, which doesn't require the flags parameter on add/set. I believe it uses the more recent C library.

```
// This string must never be produced from the database.
// Also, the empty string must never be possible.
$WAIT_FOR_IT = '**WAIT**'

do {
   // The WAIT special value must expire quickly; otherwise, a failed
   // task could hang all other requesters for the same key.
   if ($memcache->add('key', $WAIT_FOR_IT, 1)){
      $get_result = db_lookup('key');
      $memcache->set('key', $get_result, 600);
   } else {
      $get_result = $memcache->get('key')
      if ($get_result == $WAIT_FOR_IT){
         // We get here if someone else is supposedly working on the value.
         // Don't wait very long.
         usleep(5000)
         $get_result = FALSE
      }
   }
} while (!$get_result)
```